# C++ : pointers change?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Just when I thought I was getting a good grasp of pointers, I'm confused again. Your insights will probably be helpful.

I guess I could state what confuses me in very general terms, like:

a) If I write `A* p = new A()`; (where `A` is some class), and then do stuff like `(*p).do_stuff()`, then the object pointed to by `p` might move in memory, so why would `p` still point to my object?

b) How are classes and member variable of classes stored in memory.

But maybe it is more useful that I tell you the problem that I have a little bit more specifically. Say I have a class `Car` that has a member variable `Engine engine_;` (where `Engine` is some other class). Fine. Now suppose that for some reason I want to create a class that has a member variable that is a pointer to an `Engine`, like:

```
class Car
{
    friend Repair;
public:
    Car() {engine_ = Engine();}
private:
    Engine engine_;
};

class Repair
{
public:
    Repair(const Car &car) : engine_(&(car.engine_)) {}
private:
    Engine *engine_;
};
```

There's no chance that `repair.engine_` will always point to my car's engine, is there (?) But even in this second version :

```
class Car
{
    friend Repair;
public:
    Car() {engine_ = new Engine();}
    ~Car() {delete engine_;}
private:
    Engine *engine_;
};
// Maybe I need/should write consts somewhere, not sure

class Repair
{
public:
    Repair(const Car &car) : engine_(car.engine_) {}
private:
    Engine *engine_;
};
```

although it seems there's more chance this will work, I don't see how / understand whether it will...

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Why would the object move in memory?

Comment: I guess my example was wrong. I should have written `A a(); A* p = &a;`. What about that?

Comment: The object will still never move.  Its lifetime may end (in this case when `a` goes out of scope), but that's a different problem entirely.

Comment: Alright, I think I'm beginning to see the light again. Thanks for helping!

Comment: An object never moves in memory.  It might be copied, but the copy is a new object.

Comment: If I may be so arrogant as to make assumptions, I assume that you mean the address of an array member, a `vector` for instance. `p = &somevector[3]`. In that case, `p` may stop pointing to the right variable if you resize the vector.

Answer (score 2):

> If I write `A* p = new A();` (where `A` is some class), and then do stuff like `(*p).do_stuff()`, then the object pointed to by p might move in memory

No, it won't. (At least, `*p` will stay were it is; if it has pointer members itself, then those may get reset to point elsewhere.)

> How are classes and member variable of classes stored in memory

As bits.

```
class Foo {
    int i;
    char *p;

  public:
     void bla();
};
```

will be represented as the bits of an `int` (probably 32) followed by those of a pointer (32 or 64), with perhaps some padding in between. The method will not take up space in your instances, it's stored separately.

As for your example, I don't exactly understand the problem. It should work if as the `Car` stays alive, and does not reset its `Engine*`, as long as the `Repair` object lives. (It doesn't look particularly robust, though.)

Comment: I still don't get it. Why do you say the object pointed to by p won't move? what if at some point it increases in size and needs to be reallocated?

Comment: Your Foo example is not very helpful to me because its members are not classes.

Comment: Which version of my example are you talking about?

Comment: @user1367124: (1) Objects don't change their size magically. You will have done that yourself. (2) That doesn't matter much. When a class instance contains another class instance, its bit pattern just gets inserted inline, again possibly with padding. (3) The one with the `Engine*`, though they are very similar.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "It doesn't look particularly robust"? Also, do you think the first version is better (because it's then impossible to lose the car's engine)?

Answer (score 0):

in both case 1) and case 2) there is no guarantee that `repair.engine_` will always point to your car, because it's a friend class and not a member of class 'Car'

Comment: Who cares about the "friend" aspect. Others seem to disagree with you that `repair.engine_` won't point to my car's engine...

Comment: `repair.engine_` will always point to the `Engine` of the `Car` object that is passed in to the constructor... until you change the engine of the `Car`. If at some point you create a new `Engine` and save that in the `Engine` field of the car, the `Engine` pointer in `Repair` will not be updated.

Comment: Well, if I understand things correctly now, the Engine pointer in Repair will then point to the Car's new engine, right? this is what I want. Edit : Wait, no, it will be updated in case 1 but not in case 2, am I right? If so then the two cases are actually very different, right?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the object does not move in memory when you do stuff like `(*p).do_stuff();`.  You must have misunderstood something that you learned at some point.

For your second question, member functions and member variables are stored in different places in memory.  The code for member functions is only generated once for each class, not once for each instance of the class.  This code is stored at some location in memory.

As for member variables, this is what people are talking about when they mention your object's location in memory.  For example, if you have a class like

```
class MyClass{
  private:
    int a;
    int b;
    double c;
  public:
    void fun();
};
```

and we assume that an instance of it is stored at memory location 0x0000, this means that `a` is at location 0x0000, b is at 0x0004, and c would be at 0x0008 (or something like this depending on how memory is laid out).  The function `fun()` is stored somewhere else entirely.

Now if we make another instance of `MyClass`, it's `a` variable might be at 0x000C, it's `b` might be at 0x0010, and it's `c` at 0x0014.  Finally, it's `fun()` is in the exact same location as `fun()` from the first instance.

Comment: what if *p is an std::vector<int> and I change its size? what about classes that have other classes as member variables (which are not of constant size?)

Comment: Those don't add to the size of the class. Classes like std::vector have an internal pointer that is pointed to newly allocated memory when the vector is resized. The vector is still the same size because it is only comprised of a pointer and some size information. You're perhaps more used to other languages where resizing a container contributes to an object that contains that container. In C++, pointers are just effectively integers that tell you that somewhere far away is some other piece of memory. You don't even have any information in the pointer telling you how big that memory chunk is

Comment: @user1367124: You can easily see that what cppguy said is true by writing a simple program. `vector<int> a; cout << sizeof(a); << endl; a.reserve(500); cout << sizeof(a);`. Both will the same number (28 or something small like that), even though calling `a.reserve(500);` increased the size of the vector to hold at least 500 `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers in C++ allocated with `new` don't move.  You might be thinking of `malloc`, where a pointer can be `realloc`'d and possibly go to a new location as a result.

Bjarne Stroustrup felt that C++ containers generally provided a better way to deal with the wish to have dynamically sized memory:

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#renew

In order to allow for movement and reorganization of memory, some systems use abstract handles that need to be locked into pointers before you can use them...such as Windows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366584(v=vs.85).aspx

Using something abstract which you lock into pointers might make sense in a system that needs to do some kind of periodic memory defragmentation.  But C++ doesn't pay the cost for that indirection by default, you'd implement it only in cases where it makes sense to do so.

*(On the downside, with non-movable pointers if you allocate a million objects and then delete 999,999 of them... that one object which is left may stay sitting way up at the top of the address space.  The OS/paging system is supposed to be smarter than to let this be a problem, but if your allocator is custom this might leave your heap at a big size.  For instance: if you're using a memory-mapped file as a backing store for your objects...you'll be stuck with a large and mostly empty disk file.)*

Comment: "some systems use abstract handles that need to be locked into pointers before you can use them...such as Windows:" – the last Windows version that did this was Windows 3.1; the concept of memory handles was totally obsoleted by virtual memory. On the other hand, a very similar system is used by the .NET runtime.

Comment: @Philipp AFAIK the distinction lost after Win 3.1 was there being a difference between Global and Local alloc.  GlobalAlloc continued to be used, and requires GlobalLock before converting into a usable pointer.  It can be moved by GlobalRealloc...this is in XP+... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366590(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, these functions are still there, but only for compatibility purposes. The MSDN Library mentions that the global and local functions (and especially the flags creating "moveable" memory) should not be used any more. AFAIK they are just a userspace compatibility layer that wraps the normal heap/virtual functions.

Comment: Compatibility is still a purpose, OLE and DDE code was on the rise post-Win3.1 and is probably still being written today...somewhere.  I said "some systems use abstract handles that need to be locked into pointers before you can use them...such as Windows".  I didn't say they used it *all the time*.  :)  I do note that it says this new HeapAlloc thing doesn't require a lock and returns a void pointer, but can still be moved if realloc'd...so I guess you just have to know if that can happen by convention.